# Can one icon/button click perform 2 actions?

Tags: sharepoint-online

Is there a way of making one click do two things? Ideally i'd like a click on an icon to play an audio file and go to a document library... is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Why not.. write both the event under click action.

Answer (score 0):

Yes You can perform two different events on click..You can write the both events under single on click bind or in case if you pushing second event later you can bind them differently.

**Case 1 : Binding both events with single binding**

```
$("#Icon-ID").on('click', function() {
//do something to play audio file

//Open document library in modal pop up. Since redirection would stop audio file.
SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog({
    url: document_library_url,
    width: 500,
    height: 500,
    title: "Title of the Dialog"
});
});
```

**Case 2 : Binding both events in separate bindings**

```
$("#Icon-ID").on('click', function() {
//do something to play audio file
});
$("#Icon-ID").on('click', function() {
//Open document library in modal pop up. Since redirection would stop audio file.
SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog({
    url: document_library_url,
    width: 500,
    height: 500,
    title: "Title of the Dialog"
});
});
```

Comment: Fabulous. Now I just have to work out how to apply that code :-) I'm still at the applying everything through CEWP stage of Sharepoint

Answer (score -1):

Write a code under click event of controller.

```
$("#controllerId").click(function(){

    alert("play an audio file");

    window.location.href = "http:DocumentUrl";
});
```